# How to solve: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, string, list, python-requests, integer

I'm having a trouble passing my email Ids into function and then generating API query for each in order to receive a list with customerIds

this is my code:

```
email = [733867970, 733870466]

def get_email_details(email, token, userId):
    headers = { 'accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'token': token,
        'userId': userId}
    endpoint = 'request/' + str(email) + '/details'
    r = requests.get(url = HOST + endpoint, headers = headers, verify=False)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    final_list = []
    for each_req in data:
        final_list.append(each_req['customerId'])
    return final_list


for x in email:
    myCustList = get_request_details(email, token, userId)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 11, in get_email_details
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: change `myCustList = get_request_details(email, token, userId)` to `myCustList = get_request_details(x, token, userId)`

Comment: I changed just now, thanks for catching this, but same error stil occurs. Any ideas what else could be wrong? thanks!

Comment: Please show all the traceback,we don't know why would it happened.Or you could show us what's the `data`?Add it in your post.

Comment: I'm guessing that `each_req` is a string and not a dict as you're expecting.

Comment: jizhihaoSAMA and Rickey I'm trying to approach this problem differently and posted a new question with additional details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392355/run-functions-for-each-item-on-python-list-separately-and-append-results-retriev Would you be able to help me with this? thanks!